# Socket Exception while passing data to EventHub in Xamarin

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, async-await, azure-eventhub

I am trying to pass data off the Xamarin application to EventHub. The issue now is the application never catches SocketException. I am continuously experiencing poor internet connection and no connection sometimes, hence SocketException regularly occurs with error '*can't reach host*'.

```
     Main Function;
      try
        {
          SendMessageToEventHub().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
          //I know i shouldn't be using GetAwaiter().GetResult() here in the main 
          //function but this is just for the test.
        }
      catch(Exception e)
        {
            //Never reaches here.
        }
```

I realized SocketException is an asynchronous exception, so I tried making the whole code synchronous with no luck.

```
     public async Task SendMessageToEventHub()
    {
        var connectionStringBuilder = new EventHubsConnectionStringBuilder(EventHubConnectionString)
        {
            EntityPath = EventHubName
        };
        eventHubClient = EventHubClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionStringBuilder.ToString());
        eventClientDatas = new List<EventClientData>();
        var eventClientData = new EventClientData() { id = null, timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow, mac = "test", nodeMac = "", rawData = "", rssi = 12, type = "Phone" };
        eventClientDatas.Add(eventClientData);
        Console.WriteLine($"Sending Message: {eventClientData}");
        await eventHubClient.SendAsync(new EventData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(eventClientDatas))));
        await eventHubClient.CloseAsync();
    }
```

Comment: I didn't get what your issue is. Can you try running it with no connection? You should either get SocketException or TimeoutException.

Comment: @SerkantKaraca, after numerous tests, what I found was, it is actually catching SocketException. However, the visual studio still throws an error box with the exception. At this point, I thought the app was crashing but it is not. If I run the app without connecting the phone to VS debugger, then everything works fine.

Comment: I wonder if you have enabled first-chance exceptions in your debugger config. Please note that client has internal retry component which will handle transient exceptions. If you have enabled first-chance exceptions on VS, then you might still be seeing those exceptions not bubbling up all the way to the caller.

Comment: Thank you @SerkantKaraca. that was the case.